# NTFS file system reference

Tags: c, windows, ntfs

i need to understand full NTFS structure, how partition tables are made and how the directories/files are stored on disk. Who know good reference?

Thank you

Comment: Why are people marking this as "off-topic", asking about NTFS data structures is clearly programming related

Answer (score 2):

I think this is mostly for Linux, but it might help:
http://kcrazy.timeegg.com/Favorites/ntfsdoc.htm

NTFS' official website might also help:
http://www.ntfs.com/

Finally, if all else fails, Wikipedia!:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS

Hope this helps!

Comment: ntfs.com does not look like an official website to me.  The WHOIS record shows some random company in Ontario.  It looks like this company also sells backup and repair solutions.  Strangely they also have a lot of speculation about WinFS, which was planned for Vista but was canned.

Answer (score 2):

How about Microsoft's handily named "[How NTFS Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)".

Comment: yes but it not cover the binary structure

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://hackipedia.org/Disk%20formats/File%20systems/NTFS,%20Windows%20NT%20Filesystem%20%28Windows%29/html,%20ntfs-3g-doc%20%28collection%29/) is the best I could find. Anyways, give a look to the NTFS-3G driver, as it should describe pretty well what you're asking for. I doubt you can find anything official from MS anyways, as the format is closed.